# How can I find out the destination server of a VPN connection's utun interface?

Tags: network, vpn

When connected to my VPN (in this case using the OpenVPN app Viscosity) it creates a utun interface that looks like this when queried using `ifconfig utun10`:

```
utun10: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    inet 10.20.0.30 --> 10.20.0.30 netmask 0xffff0000
    inet6 aaaa::bbbb:cccc:dddd:eeee%utun10 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x17
    inet6 ffff:aaaa:bbbb:cccc::dddd prefixlen 64
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
```

From the command line or (better yet) programmatically, is there any way I can figure out the hostname or IP address of the VPN server that's on the other end of `utun10`?

Comment: I don’t think sparklab documents where on the filesystem (if even it logs to the filesystem) the [connection log containing this data resides](https://www.sparklabs.com/support/kb/article/logs-and-information-to-provide-support-staff/). You need the application logs to tell you what the host is - it’s too late to back track from the `utun10` since the other active interfaces will have the live connection to the server  - the tunnel describes what gets tunneled - not to where the first hop is

Comment: @bmike Is that to say then that `utun10` (and any `utun` interface in general) does not have any kind of metadata or method for figuring out where its traffic goes? I'm still new to virtual interfaces, so I wasn't sure if their data goes somewhere identifiable or if it's just a general purpose channel where the app that created it simply receives its input and then does whatever it wants with it. (In the case of Viscosity, that's probably sending it over a UDP connection to the VPN server.)

Comment: Yes - I’ll answer as best I can. My VPN that hits AT&T goes out en0 to a 12.x.x.x and my other VPN that hits Level 3 goes out en0 to 4.x.x.x on IPv4 but you could have an IPv6 endpoint, so be sure to check both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best / worst you can do from the tunnel is get the routing for all networks that that tunnel has established:

```
netstat -lnI utun10
```

It should track closely to what you see for the `ifconfig` on the routing. It’s not really possible to deduce from which gateway you brought up this tunnel since you contacted the VPN server on another interface (likely en0) if you have one Ethernet only built in on the Mac. So the **short answer to your question is that information isn’t retrievable from `utunX`**

You will need to get at the logs of your VPN client and/or run netstat on another interface to see which gateway takes the tunneled traffic.

Here is the information for the mac client I think you are using:

- https://www.sparklabs.com/support/kb/article/logs-and-information-to-provide-support-staff/

Once you have that application log, you might be able to search in console.app if it perhaps logs to the unified database / file storage logs on macOS. Worst case, you need that client (or another client) to log connection details so you can automate scripting your query.

Comment: Is there a way to get `netstat` not to truncate IPv6 addresses when using `-I utun10`? The `-W` argument doesn't appear to work in this case.

Comment: The `-l` in my answer prints the full IPv6 on Monterey. Adding W isn’t needed @BriBri

Comment: Looks like that's just an issue with `netstat` in macOS 10.14 then. Tried it out on a Monterey system and got the full addresses. Currently it looks like you are correct that it's not possible, and in the case of the VPN I'm testing with, there's nothing useful that can be gleamed from any of the IP addresses (v4 or v6) that are associated with `utun10`.

Comment: You’ve got a great bounty up - if someone else is more clever, I bet you’ll get another answer. Short of dumping the traffic from en0 or whichever interface sends packets to the tunnel endpoint and then filtering out other traffic to all non-VPN gateways, I can’t think of a way besides getting the client to tell you directly what happened when you connected…

Comment: If this comes down to 10.14 netstat being dumb, surely there's an alternative (perhaps third party) utility? Maybe something in MacPorts? (Since Homebrew dropped support for 10.14.)

Comment: @bmike Alas no one that was more clever than us posted an answer, but I think your answer is likely the correct one nonetheless. The good news is that I have found alternative methods for discovering which VPN a utun interface corresponds to. (e.g. sending requests through the interface to a VPN's API that checks its public IP address, or scripting Viscosity with AppleScript to check what its active connections are)

Comment: One think I love, questions here can get answers months and years later. Thanks for asking a very nice question.